# Jquery setTimeout not respecting the timing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used setTimeout more than once, and I never found any problem, except this time.
In this case setTimeout calls my method again, but not after the delay of 3000 (or whatever) but just immediately, I can't understand why.. (in the function refreshPhalanx)
Here is the code:
(I used to create a random delay between 3000 and 3500 ms and store it in the var "msec" , but after I used 3000, to test it in case the mistake was in the construction of the delay, but  still no result..)

```js
var n=1;
function refreshPhalanx(id){
    console.debug(id);
    //$('.refreshPhalanxLink').click();
    if($('#'+id).length){
        console.debug('still going'+n++);
        var msec=Math.floor((Math.random()/2+3)*1000)
        console.debug(msec);
        setTimeout(refreshPhalanx(id), 3000); //I used msec before, but I put 3000 to test if it was just a mistake into the calculation of the milliseconds, or a problem with setTimeout method.
    }
    else
        alert('Alle ore  '+new Date($.now())+' la missione risulta ritirata.');        
}

function delay(){
    if($('.phalanx').length){
        console.debug('appending');
        $('.eventFleet').each(function(){
            $(this).append('<button currentevent="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="buttons">calcola rientro</button>');
        })
        console.debug('appending');
        $('.buttons').click(function(){
            console.debug('click --->'+ $(this).attr('currentEvent'));
            refreshPhalanx($(this).attr('currentevent'));
        })
        console.debug('appending');
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(delay, 2000);
        console.debug('delaying');
    }
}

delay();
```

Comment: `setTimeout(refreshPhalanx(id), 3000);` contains a function call not the _reference_ to the function.

Comment: What do you think `refreshPhalanx(id)` does? Answer: it calls the function. Immediately. Its *return value* gets passed to `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` is **not** jQuery, but plain vanilla DOM 0. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
setTimeout(refreshPhalanx(id), 3000);
```

means: call the function `refreshPhalanx(id)` and set the return value as first parameter of `setTimeout`.

The synopsis of setTimeout is `function setTimeout(callback, milliseconds)` where callback is a callable function or a string with the name of a function.

Change your code to

```
 setTimeout(function () {
       refreshPhalanx(id);
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: Yes i see.. i was confused by the fact that when I used this method in the past, my function hadn't any parameters and i used to put just the string.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `function` as the first argument to `setTimeout`. However with `refreshPhalanx(id)` you aren’t passing a function but the *return value* of that function which in your case is `undefined`.

To pass a function with parameters simply wrap the function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  refreshPhalanx(id)
},3000);
```

And it’s most likely the case that

```
setTimeout(delay, 2000);
```

worked correctly because here you just passed the function name without executing it with `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting your call in an anonymous function within the `setTimeout()` as such:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    refreshPhalanx(id);
}, 3000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    delay();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: the call of delay is working as its's not `delay()` but just `delay`.